# Insert SQL Keyword from .sql file

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

I am trying to insert new record into my database through a .sql file

```
INSERT INTO CisZdravotnickeProstredky(Kod,Nazev) VALUES
(N'0048367', N'SET AUTOTRANSFÚZNÍ BELLOVAC ABT-ZÁKLADNÍ SET')
```

Problem is with the keyword "SET"

How to insert this `nvarchar`?

Comment: "Problem is with the keyword "SET"" - What makes you think that? Personally, I think the problem is that you forgot the keyword `Values`

Comment: @ZoharPeled problem is that "SET" is SQL keyword which do not make me my insert work. sorry forget for "VALUES"

Comment: SET is inside quotes and part of a (n)varchar. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: 'AUTOTRANSFÚZNÍ' is not a recognized SET option.

Comment: How do you execute this statement? I've tried this statement in my local dbms (with simplified table structure) and it executed successfully

Comment: i have this code saved in .sql file and this file is execute throught entity framework context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText("resources/sql/CisDrgMarker.sql"));

Comment: This is not a problem with TSQL. Most likely the parsing of the `.sql` file provides unexpected results. The insert statement you have now in the question is perfectly fine, assuming both columns are `nvarchar` and both have sufficient length for the values.

Comment: Is there a trigger on table `CisZdravotnickeProstredky` ?

Comment: @AakashM there is no trigger